# ts-jest command line tool for unit tests

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, ts-node

I am learning TypeScript on my Linux laptop, I installed Node.js and TypeScript and with the help of `ts-node` I can quickly compile and test my code snippets.

Now I want to add unit test for my code snippets, and at the organization I work for Jest is used, so I installed Jest and `ts-jest`.

When I code I want to create an example file, compile, and test it with `ts-node`:

```
ts-node example.ts
```

Next I want to create create an unit test file, compile, and test it with `ts-jest`:

```
ts-jest example.test.ts
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. Most tutorials explain at length how to integrate Jest and `ts-jest` into a web framework, like React, with many changes in JSON configuration files. Is there a way to use the command line with Jest or `ts-jest` to compile and run a single unit test TypeScript file? I would like to stick with Jest; however, is there some other tool I can do this?

Comment: You still run the tests with `jest ...`, you just use the `ts-jest` *preset* per e.g. https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/presets#basic-usage.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe in the link you sent a config file was mentioned can I place that file somewhere so it is used all the way around? Because it seems to placed in the root of a project folder but I want to explicitly not configure a project. With ts-node I can compile without configuration, in a convention over configuration style. I am  looking for a way without configuring something.

Comment: No, Jest won't auto-detect `ts-jest` so you need a Jest config file or config object in your package file.